# Problem with getting access to index of a map in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I have a map<string, dynamic> ,and want to show it's components in cards by ListView.Builder, but the problem is by getting access to this map's indexes..

When running the app, it return "null" in the card!!

I have tried many solutions that I saw in StackOverFlow for a similar issues, but without a result.

Here where I identified my map:

```
var _item;
  List listCount = [];

  Map<String, dynamic> records = {};
  String name;
```

And here where I give the var _item it's value:

```
MyCard(
                    colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    maker: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        StreamBuilder<int>(
                          stream: _stopWatchTimer2.rawTime,
                          initialData: 0,
                          builder: (context, snap) {
                            final value = snap.data;
                            final displayTime = StopWatchTimer.getDisplayTime(
                                value,
                                hours: _isHours2);
                            _item = displayTime;
                            return Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: Text(displayTime,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 30.0, color: Colors.white)),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

And here in the "Save" button I give the 1st parameter of the map and assign in name variable:

```
createAlertDialog(buildContext, context) {
    TextEditingController controller;
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      // barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Type record name',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
          ),
          content: TextField(
              controller: controller,
              onChanged: (value) {
                name = value;
              }),
          actions: [
            MaterialButton(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Text('Save'),
              onPressed: () {
                listCount.add(_item);
                print(_item);
                records[name] = _item;
                print(records);
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              elevation: 5.0,
              child: Text('Cancel'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Finally here where I tried to show it in a card by listview.builder:

```
Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: records.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return MyCard(
                  colour: Colors.cyanAccent,
                  maker: Container(
                    width: 250.0,
                    height: 75.0,
                    child: Text(
                      '${records[index]}',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

I think the problem with the 2nd parameter of itemBuilder which it (index) because I replaced this keyword with another one randomly, and get the same result when running my app "Null".

[This screenShot explain the problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvOsA.jpg)

Comment: Try replacing records[index] with records[records.keys.toList()[index]]. Seems like you are not accessing the actual String key.

Comment: @CömertTülümen
That's ammazing..
It gave me the most important part of the solution, but still want some thing else..
Your code show me the values of my map, I want it to show the keys and values together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get map entries as List as such:

```
final recordsEntries = records.entries.toList()
```

Then, you have a List of MapEntry and are able to access key and value associated for each item of the collection.

```
recordsEntries[index].key
recordsEntries[index].value
```